# Displaying loading progress of <img> element

Tags: jquery, lazy-loading, image, jquery-lazyload

I am writing a web application that deals with a large image. To make loading of the page a bit responsive, I used the Lazy Load Jquery Plugin. (http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload).

But It seems what I need is to display the progress of loading of image because the image took more than 20 secs to load.

How I am going to add an event listener for the progress for the img tag? I want display a progress in terms of percentage.

Comment: i not think you can, why not use interlaced image ?

Comment: Can you show me an example? or a site that exhibits interlaced image?

Comment: and image himself show her progress

Comment: Does it degrade the quality of the image? I get it.

Comment: no, but images file size can be a bit more bigger, quality of picture will be improved as the download advance, full quality will be at full download

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript loading progress of an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14218607/javascript-loading-progress-of-an-image)

Answer (score 0):

Other options are to show a low-quality fast-loading image in it's place until Lazy Loading replaces it.  If you really want to monitor progress, you'd probably have to do it through AJAX, like this - http://blogs.adobe.com/webplatform/2012/07/10/image-progress-event-progress/