# Get Progress of Image() loading in %

Tags: javascript

how can I get the % of a image loading on my server and show % of it's loading.
That's what I use to load image(it's for a simple download speed test).

```
var imageAddr = 'http://192.168.11.17/Cat2.JPG' + '?n=' + Math.random();
var startTime, endTime;
var downloadSize = 7616998;
var download = new Image();
download.onload = function () {
endTime = (new Date()).getTime();
showResults();
}
startTime = (new Date()).getTime();
download.src = imageAddr;
function showResults() {
  var duration = (endTime - startTime) / 1000; 
    var bitsLoaded = downloadSize * 8;
    var speedBps = (bitsLoaded / duration).toFixed(2);
    var speedKbps = (speedBps / 1024).toFixed(2);
    var speedMbps = (speedKbps / 1024).toFixed(2);
    var speedMB = speedMbps / 8;
    document.getElementById('download').innerHTML = speedMbps + 'Mbps';
}
```

Maybe there is other solutions with XMLHTTPRequest but I've tried with no succes. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14218607/javascript-loading-progress-of-an-image

Comment: no it's not a duplicate because I don't want the image to be visible and in this case onLoadStart is not fired.

Comment: You don't have to append the image to the DOM - although they do in the example I linked to - so it need not be visible.  In which case you can use `onLoadStart`.  Would that not work?