# Track progress of loading image in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, image, download, progress-bar

I am trying to display a progress bar using the progress of loading images. I tried using onload and onprogress as suggested in one previous answer but only onload works.Thanks in advance.

```
    var Img = new Image();
    Img.onload = function () {
        console.log("loaded");
    };

    Img.onprogress=function(){
        console.log("progress");
    };

    Img.src = imageUrl;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript loading progress of an image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14218607/javascript-loading-progress-of-an-image)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Ajax i.e. XHR to get progress events. See more here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22593907/6732963