# Show Progress Bar For Image Load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

Good Evening,

I am building a website and I will be loading images from a remote website. Right now the page is blank until the images completely load. I was hoping someone can show me an easy to to show progress of the images being loaded either by a percentage number or using something like a bootstrap progress bar.

Right now I am using pure HTML:

```
<img src="http://www.someWebSite.com/testImage.png" alt="Test">
```

Any Recommendations?

Comment: you want to make image become progress bar?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using bootstrap(or any other framework).
Using JQuery to make psuedo code

```
('#yourDiv').append(#loading);
('#yourImage').onLoad(function(){
     ('#yourDiv').append(#yourImage);
     ('#yourDiv').delete(#loading)
});
```

Where

1. yourDiv is the parent div,
2. Loading is loading animation
3. yourImage is the html image

Answer (score -1):

Check out this thread which explains how to display load progress of an image
[JavaScript loading progress of an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14218607/javascript-loading-progress-of-an-image)

Comment: This should be a comment