# Preload img src as original location rather than new blob with XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xmlhttprequest, blob

I'm lazyloading images through a custom `XMLHttpRequest` (there's nothing unusual in it so, to help this question remain legible, I'll omit most of it unless the issue isn't obvious without it. It's pretty much like [the following example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22593907/613305)).

I look through the `data-srcset` of each `img` element for the most appropriate size, preload it, then place it as a `src` attribute in the appropriate `img` element. The `img` elements look like the following, before preloading:

```
<img class='img img__lazyload' 
    data-srcset="/images/400/1473091018.jpg 400w,
                /images/1400/1473091018.jpg 1400w,
                /images/1800/1473091018.jpg 1800w">
```

Everything works fine. My issue is that I am not well set up for good caching practices as the `image blob` I create is placed as the `src` of the element, of course, rather than the real url to the actual location of where the image was sourced from. So instead of:

```
src="blob:http://example.com/2f3e365d-be2d-47ca-ba72-dceb5552adc5"
```

I would like the `src` to be something like this instead:

```
src="/images/1400/1473091018.jpg"
```

so that the browser can realise it already has the image cached (if so) and use that, rather than seeing a blob that's unique and loading the image each time the site is visited, despite having loaded it previously. The problem is, I'm not sure how to go about this as I'm only familiar with creating an `image blob` like so:

```
xmlHTTP.onload = function (e) {
    var blob = new Blob([this.response]);
    thisImg.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
};
```

I create the `src` in the `img` element by replacing the entire element with my `image` object like so (as well as copying the attributes of the original over):

```
var img = new Image(); // creates a new image object which includes the above onload function
$('.img-container').eq(index).find('img').replaceWith(img);
```

I'm guessing I can't avoid using a `blob` if using an `XMLHttpRequest`, but my attempts to compare this to the source of the file have proved fruitless so far. I'm using `XMLHttpRequest` to provide feedback to a progress bar as the image loads for a slideshow.

---

## Update

I've been developing with caching turned off and just *assumed* that, as the url of `src` showed a temporary, unique `blob` url, that it would prevent any form of caching.

Am I imagining, now that I've tried turning caching back on, that the browser does cache the images relative to their original source url? As in, even though I've got `blob` showing as the `src`, that because it was retrieved originally from `http://example.com/....` that the browser will recognise that it has the image in its cache?

Comment: Your xhr request is cached too. No worries.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation.