# loading percent for img on React

Tags: reactjs, image, percentage

I am displaying an image on React web app.

My code is like below:

```
<img
    alt={fileName}
    onLoad={onLoad}
    src={url}
/>
```

I want to display an indicator around the image, which tells user about the image download percentage.

I know with `onLoad` property is to provide a function which will be called when image finishes loading, but I don't know how to detect the image downloading percentage (or downloaded size).

Is there a property like `onLoad`? I tried `onProgress` but it didn't get fired.

I've read this question [JavaScript loading progress of an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14218607/javascript-loading-progress-of-an-image).

But [the highest vote answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22593907/853191) in this question doesn't answer my question.

That answer needs to create a new Image() instance manually, what I want is to know whether there is a built-in support for `onProgress` property, or please advise how to build a lower mechanism to support this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript loading progress of an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14218607/javascript-loading-progress-of-an-image)

Comment: @BoyWithSilverWings, I edited the question and added the explanation for answers in that question don't resolve my problem. Thanks.

Comment: No, there is no native support for this.

Comment: @BoyWithSilverWings Thanks for the info. Any advice if I want to add such a custom property to `img` tag?

Answer (score 1):

I try to use onProgress built in property in img tag jsx but in doesn't work, not sure why it is exclusive for audio or video

So I create my own way to get the percentage of image by manually fetching it as `arrrayBuffer` in `XMLHttpRequest`, and here how it looks like

```
...
componentDidMount(): void {
  const {src, onProgress, onLoadStart, onLoadEnd} = this.props;

  if (onProgress || onLoadStar || onLoadEnd) {
    this.renderImage(src);
    return;
  }

  this.setState({src});
}

renderImage = (src: string) => {
  const {onProgress, onLoadStart, onLoadEnd} = this.props;
  const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
  request.open('GET', src, true);
  request.onprogress = function (e) {
    const loadPercentage = Math.floor((e.loaded / e.total) * 100);
    onProgress && onProgress(loadPercentage);
  };
  request.onloadstart = () => {
    onLoadStart && onLoadStart();
  };
  request.onloadend = () => {
    const blob = new Blob([request.response]);
    const source = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    this.setState({src: source});

    onLoadEnd && onLoadEnd();
  };
  request.send();
};

render(): ReactNode {
  return <img src={this.state.src}/>
}
...
```