# jQuery preload large image with % loaded progress update

Tags: jquery, loader, preload

I have a rather large world map image at about 900k. I'd like to show loading text with live % completed, like "Loading Map 33%". I know the code I have below is obviously wrong. Any ideas how to correctly achieve this?

```
 $(function(){
    var map_image = $("#world_map_img"),
        imgPercent = (100 / map_image.length),
        curPercent = 0
    map_image.on('load',function(){
        curPercent += imgPercent;
        $(".img_load_percent").text(Math.round(curPercent));
        $(".loader").hide()
        map_image.animate({"opacity":"1.0"}, 1000)
    });
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript loading progress of an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14218607/javascript-loading-progress-of-an-image)

Comment: Is that loading a remote image from a URL?

Comment: How are you loading your image?

Comment: Just a local image <img id="world_map_img" src="images/world_pixel_map.png" class="map_large world_map_img" />

Comment: even if it's stored locally you could still pull it using an asynchronous request like in the provided post above.